# Visual Studio debugger shows Date Time as Ticks when mouse hover instead of an understandable Date String Format

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-debugging, debuggervisualizer

In visual studio (I'm using 2019), during debugging, when I hover over a **DateTime** object, it shows the date in Ticks instead of a readable date string (such as YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss, etc).

The picture below shows this annoying behavior.

[image: Text]

I remember in my old visual studio 2017, it showed date-time objects in "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.ttt" format.
How do I change this?

Comment: What does `LoadAreaTo.ToString()` result in?

Comment: Thanks for asking this because looking for an answer taught me that you can pin multiple preview formats.

Comment: I have added an answer to describe the issue in detail and hope it could help you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I agree with **reynoldsbj**. I think you have pinned the **Ticks** property in the `LoadAreaTo` Drop down menu bar so that it will overwrite the default **Date** property.

This is a video about the detailed description:

[image]

You should **unpin** the property **Ticks** so that it will show date-time objects in `YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.tt` format.

Answer (score 3):

Click the dropdown in that previewer and unpin Ticks or pin Date if you want to see both.